# Hide HTML components in email

Tags: exm

**Sitecore version**: 9.0.2

**Business scenario**: If a customer leaves with items in cart, we have to send a mail with the details of the items in the cart. At max, we have to display only 4 items in the mail.

**The HTML structure and the mail**:

The HTML layout contains a table with 4 nested tables inside it for each item in the cart (considering the scenario for the maximum items to be displayed).

**Way ahead**: So, as the requirements are clear let's move to the implementation.

Given the different business dependencies, we are going for an automatic campaign with the inbuilt HTML as the template.

**Approach and blockers:**
We thought that we will use tokens to apply '`display: none`' to the tables which we will have to hide. But the approach failed. More detail on it is [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20395/display-none-attribute-is-not-working).

Post that we tried to apply the suggestions provided in the answer mentioned above. We tried it both ways, in-line as well as through the class. But the success evaded us whenever we checked the mails in our mailbox.

**Mail-systems in question:**
Right now we are focusing on three mails system:
1. Gmail
2. Hotmail
3. Outlook

But yes the business has asked for all.

I believe that what I am trying to achieve is not something uncommon but there is something which we are missing.

Please help me to solve this puzzle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you generate this mail yourselves, why bother hiding stuff?  Why not just not-render the items you don't need?

Comment: @MarkCassidy: Please elaborate it more or point me to a link. That will be helpful.

Comment: This site is not a support portal. Your question is regarding a very bespoke requirement to your solution and the way you've chosen to implement it. Further - this question is really just a rewording of the question you linked to - on how to hide elements from your mail.